# Bootstrap 3 Modal box - Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This Bootstrap 3 modal box code works file on [codePen](http://codepen.io/jitendravyas/pen/zLKAs) but giving error inside my rails app.

This error shows in console when I click on thumbnail. When the code is integrated inside my app. But on codepen example it works fine.

my browser is the latest version of Google chrome on Windows.

**Error**

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 
     <figure class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/450/">
      <figcaption class="truncate caption"> blah blah blah blah blah blah </figcaption>
    </figure>
```

**jquery**

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function(){
    $('.modal-body').empty();
    var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");
    $('.modal-title').html(title);
    $($(this).parents('div').html()).appendTo('.modal-body');
    $("#myModal").modal({show:true});
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="row borrowers-thumbnails">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <figure class='thumbnail'>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/450/">
      <figcaption class="truncate caption"> blah blah blah blah blah blah </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>



<div id="myModal" class="modal fade campaign-borrowers" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am too facing same problem. Does this problem resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this in mvc

```
 $("body").on("click", "a.dialog-window", null, function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $link = $(this); // Reference to <a/> link
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    // this is for future commemnt 
    //$('#myModal .modal-title').html('');
    //$('#myModal').modal('show');
    //$('#myModal .te').html("Loading please wait..");

    $('#divLoading').show();
    if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');}
    else {$.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#myModal .modal-title').html($link.text());
            $('#myModal .te').html(data);
            //  $('#myModal .te').html($.parseHTML(data)); // this remove existing the css
            $('#myModal').modal();
        }).success(function () {
            $('input:text:visible:first').focus();
            $('#divLoading').hide();
        });}
 });
$('#divLoading').hide();
```

This is jquery

now plesae put this on layout page or any where

```
<!-- /spinner -->
<div id="divLoading" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #EAF3FB; z-index: 30001; opacity: .8; filter: alpha(opacity=70);">
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 40%; color: White;">
        <span style="color: #365E94; font-weight: bold;">Loading, please wait...</span><img alt="" src="../../Content/images/loading.gif" />
    </p>
</div>
<!-- /spinner -->

<!-- /.modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"><div class="te">Please wait...</div></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

and action link for the Use in the applicatio just put class on 
and use this model popup:

```
     @Html.ActionLink("title of model popup or button name", "Create", "PatientProfile", new { id = item.PatientId }, new { @class = "dialog-window" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to close your `img` tag properly here using `/>`:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/450/" />
```

Comment: I added `/>` but problem is still there and when I check image path inside Chrome dev tools. `/>` is not there.

Comment: Remove Cache and reload again after adding `/>`

Comment: @BluAngel I checked in incognito mode in chrome. and it shows fine in view source `<img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/460/" />` but problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

heyy try this its working....

```
$(function() {
$(".thumbnail").click(function(){
    $('.modal-body').empty();
    var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");
    $('.modal-title').html(title);
    $($(this).parents('div').html()).appendTo('.modal-body');
    $("#myModal").modal({show:true});
});
});
```

Comment: I replaced mine code with yours. but still getting same error

Comment: it's working fine for me in codepen too http://codepen.io/jitendravyas/pen/zLKAs which i have already added to question

Comment: is it a problem with jquery 1.9? I changed jquery to 1.9 in your fiddle and now it's giving the same error.

Comment: heyy come for chat my email id is yogichordiya@gmail.com.
Please delete this comment after reading.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48680/discussion-between-yogichordiya-and-jitendra-vyas)